# AVQueuePlayer - using slider to control all audio tracks at once

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, uislider, avqueueplayer

I have multiple audio files that I want to play continuously and be able to control it with `UISlider`. I was using `AVAudioPlayer` but there was problem with gaps between each tracks. So I found `AVQueuePlayer` and now there are no gaps. But now I have problem with set `AVQueuePlayer` to right asset and time to play when `UISlider` value changed.

I have different duration of each tracks and I want to slider have same slice for each track so I get maximum duration of biggest track and then get acceleration for each track. Here is how I update slider when AVQueuePlayer is playing:

```
func updateSliderProgress() {
        var value: Float = 0
        if let track = tracks[self.playingIndex] {
            value = Float(self.playingIndex) * self.maximumDuration + Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(audioQueuePlayer.currentTime())) * track.acceleration
        }
        playerSlider.setValue(value, animated: false)
    }
```

And here is notification when AVPlayerItem did end:

```
func playerItemDidReachEnd(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.playingIndex++
...
}
```

It's working and UISlider is correctly progressing. But I have problem with other way:

```
@IBAction func playerSliderValueChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
    let seconds = Double(self.getSeekTime(self.playerSlider.value))
    audioQueuePlayer.seekToTime(CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(seconds, 1000))
}
```

Function `seekToTime` is inherit from `AVPlayer` and it sets time just for current track, right? So is it possible to change current `AVPlayerItem` (by index or something like that) and then apply time in that item? I found just method `advanceToNextItem` but I was hoping in more functions with changing current item.

So for now only solution which comes to my mind is that each time user uses slider I create new `AVQueuePlayer` use `advanceToNextItem` to set right track and then use `seekToTime` to get to correct time. Is there better solution?